# Catch "psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out" error in shell script

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, sh

I have 2 shell scripts which i use to connect and upgrade postgresql database schema.

in first script which is Database.sh, i have provided database connection string and call to another bash script. Below is the sample code of Database.sh file

```
export PGHOST="1.2.3.4"
export PGPORT="5432"
export PGUSER="postgres"
export PGPASSWORD="testing1234"
export PGDATABASE="testdb"

sh -f UpgradeScripts/UpgradeDB.sh
```

This UpgradeDB.sh file calls several sql files and execute them on postgres servers. Below is a sample code of UpgradeDB.sh file

```
FOLDER_PATH='UpgradeScripts/Scripts'

psql -f ${FOLDER_PATH}/changescript_1.sql
psql -f ${FOLDER_PATH}/changescript_2.sql
psql -f ${FOLDER_PATH}/changescript_3.sql
psql -f ${FOLDER_PATH}/changescript_4.sql
psql -f ${FOLDER_PATH}/changescript_5.sql
psql -f ${FOLDER_PATH}/changescript_6.sql
```

sometimes when i run Database.sh file and database server is not accessible then i get *could not connect to server* error, i want to enhace my code  to catch/read this error and retry after some time(will use sleep to hold for some time).

Comment: You could use [`pg_isready`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-isready.html) to test if Postgres is available

Comment: maybe working with return codes helps getting the status of a query... https://serverfault.com/questions/981541/psql-exit-code-2-in-bashscript

Comment: I cannot see the script you are using to connect to the database